# Select rows from multiple tables even if data is not present in one of them

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables:
"users" with id, name...
"events" with id, type...
"visits" with id, userid, eventid, visitate...
"comments" with id, userid, eventid, commentdate...
Now, I want to select users, visits, comments given a eventid. That is, select all data about all users that have visited and/or commented a given event.
I tried with:
(given an eventid=16)

```
SELECT 
users.*,
visits.*,
comments.*
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN visits ON (visits.userid=users.id)
LEFT JOIN comments ON (comments.userid=users.id)
WHERE (users.id,visitDate,commentDate) IN (
    SELECT
    DISTINCT visits.userid AS userId,
    MAX(visits.visitdate) AS visitDate,
    MAX(comments.commentdate) AS commentDate
    FROM `visits`
    LEFT JOIN comments ON (comments.userid=visits.userid AND comments. eventid =16)
    WHERE visits. eventid =16
    GROUP BY visits.userid
)
GROUP BY users.id,visits.id,comments.id
```

In my DB two users have visited event 16 but only one has left a comment,
Now, since the second user has no corresponding comment, the result is only one row. I need to get two rows, even if the second user has no comment.
Is it possible to achieve that in a single query?

IMPORTANT: every user can visit an event more than once, and leave more than one comment. I don't need to get all the visits and/or comments, just the last. That is:

1. user.John has visited event=16 the last time at 2021.10.7 and left last comment "Very good"
2. user.Paul has visited event=16 the last time at 2021.11.9 and left no comment (NULL)
   That's why I tried to use

```
DISTINCT visits.userid AS userId,
    MAX(visits.visitdate) AS visitDate,
    MAX(comments.commentdate) AS commentDate
```

Comment: why do you use a WHERE clause if you don't want to reduce the number of rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```sql
WITH 
  lastComment AS (SELECT userid, MAX(comments.id) AS lastid FROM comments WHERE eventid = 16 GROUP BY userid),
  lastVisit AS (SELECT userid, MAX(visits.id) AS lastid FROM visits WHERE eventid = 16 GROUP BY userid)
SELECT *
FROM users
  LEFT JOIN lastComment ON lastComment.userid = users.id
  LEFT JOIN lastVisit ON lastVisit.userid = users.id
  LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.id = lastComment.lastid AND lastComment.userid = users.id
  LEFT JOIN visits ON visits.id = lastVisit.lastid AND lastVisit.userid = users.id
WHERE
  lastComment.lastid IS NOT NULL
  OR
  lastVisit.lastid IS NOT NULL
```

1. First we get the last comment/visit by each user for the given event
2. Then we take only the users who have either visited or commented the given event
3. Then we get the corresponding last comment/visit

Comment: Thank you all. I can't check your suggestions right now, but I realized that omitted to say that a user can have visited an event e.g. 50 times and left 40 comments. I want to get  only 1 row for each user with last visit and last comment if present. Pardon

Comment: It should be fine, but "(SELECT * FROM comments WHERE userid = users.id AND eventid = events.id ORDER BY comments.id DESC LIMIT 1) AS lastComment" gives error #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s). I could use "(SELECT CONCAT(...)...) AS lastComment" which is not so confortable

Comment: Thanks for answering, but no way: it gives me only rows with visit AND comment...

Comment: Great. It works. Thank you very much.